# A countable complete theory with $f_T(\kappa)=(\text{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$

Tags: model-theory

How to find a countable complete theory $T$ such that $f_T(\kappa)=(\text{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$ holds for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$?

Here $f_T(\kappa)$ is defined as $\sup\{|S_1(M)|\,|\,M\models T,\,|M|=\kappa\}$ and $\text{ded}(\kappa)$ is defined as $\sup\{|I|\,|\,I \text{ contains a dense subset of size }\kappa\}=\sup\{\lambda\,|\,\text{there is a linear order of size }\kappa\text{ with }\lambda\text{ many cuts}\}$.

Comment: What does $\operatorname{ded}(\kappa)$ mean?

Comment: @ChrisEagle The supremum of all $\lambda$ such that there is a linear order of size $\lambda$ containing a dense subset of size $\kappa$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ooops, thank you. I was quite absent of mind when editing the question. Of course $\kappa$ may not be order isomorphic to the linear order of size $\kappa$.

Comment: @Louiseeeee If my answer below settled your question, it's good practice to "accept" it, by clicking the green check mark on the left side of the answer. This removes the question from the queue of open questions. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for reminding. I am new to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the language $\{<_n\mid n\in \omega\}$. Let $T$ be the theory which says that each $<_n$ is a linear order, and let $T^*$ be the model companion of $T$. More concretely: $T^*$ says that each $<_n$ is a dense linear order without endpoints, and for all $N\in \omega$, if $I_i$ is an interval in the order $<_i$ for all $i<N$, then $\bigcap_{i<N}I_i\neq \varnothing$.

Now $T^*$ has quantifier elimination, so a complete $1$-type over $M$ is determined by all instances of $x <_n m$ and $m<_n x$ and their negations, for $m\in M$ and $n\in \omega$. Every $1$-type over $M$ is either realized in $M$, or it specifies a cut in $(M,<_n)$ for all $n\in \omega$. Thus if $|M| = \kappa$, we have $|S_1(M)|\leq (\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$. So $$f_{T^*}(\kappa)\leq (\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}.$$

To obtain equality here is slightly more complicated, because $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is defined to be the *supremum* of the number of dedekind cuts in linear orders of size $\kappa$, and this supremum might not be obtained.

*Case 1:* $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is a successor cardinal. Then the supremum is attained: there is a linear order $(L,<)$ of cardinality $\kappa$ with $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$-many dedekind cuts. Defining $M$ of cardinality $\kappa$ so that $(L,<)$ embeds in $(M,<_n)$ for all $n$, we have $|S_1(M)| = (\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$, so $f_{T^*}(\kappa)=(\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$.

*Case 2:* $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is a limit cardinal with $\mathrm{cf}(\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)) = \aleph_0$. In this case, the supremum is also attained. Write $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa) = \sup_{n\in \omega} \lambda_n$ with each $\lambda_n<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$. For each $\lambda_n$, pick a linear order $(L_n,<)$ of cardinality $\kappa$ with at least $\lambda_n$-many dedekind cuts. Now the union of the $L_n$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and has $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$-many dedekind cuts. Proceed as in Case 1. The same argument shows that the supremum is attained whenever $\mathrm{cf}(\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)) \leq \kappa$.

*Case 3:* $\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is a limit cardinal with $\mathrm{cf}(\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)) > \aleph_0$. For each $\lambda<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$, we can find a linear order $(L_\lambda,<)$ of cardinality $\kappa$ with at least $\lambda$-many dedekind cuts. Defining $M_\lambda$ of cardinality $\kappa$ so that $(L_\lambda,<)$ embeds in $(M_\lambda,<_n)$ for all $n$, we have $|S_1(M_\lambda)| \geq \lambda^{\aleph_0}$. Then $$f_{T^*}(\kappa) = \sup\{|S_1(M)|\mid M\models T, |M| = \kappa\} \geq \sup_{\lambda<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)} \lambda^{\aleph_0}.$$ But since $\mathrm{cf}(\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))>\aleph_0$, every function $\aleph_0\to \mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$ is bounded and hence can be considered as a function $\aleph_0\to \lambda$ for some $\lambda < \mathrm{ded}(\kappa)$, so $$\sup_{\lambda<\mathrm{ded}(\kappa)}  \lambda^{\aleph_0} = (\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}.$$

---

Because of this example, Keisler calls theories with $f_T(\kappa) = (\mathrm{ded}(\kappa))^{\aleph_0}$ "multiply ordered". For more examples, see Keisler's expository paper on $f_T$: [Six classes of theories](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700018541).